# Only Concat List where a property has a specific value

Tags: c#, concatenation

I have 2 lists. I only want to concat LstNewItems where SItemRequestStatus = "Add"
How can this be done ?

Below concat's both lists fully but that's not what i need.

```
radGridViewFiles.DataSource = MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl
                              .Concat(MyGlobals.lstNewItems).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to filter collection:

```
MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Concat(
    MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Where(i => i.SItemRequestStatus == "Add")).ToList();
```

I would split this in two lines for readability:

```
var itemsToAdd = MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Where(i => i.SItemRequestStatus == "Add");
radGridViewFiles.DataSource = MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Concat(itemsToAdd).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should simply use `Where` extension on your `lstNewItems` collection which will return your filtered collection:

```
radGridViewFiles.DataSource = MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl
    .Concat(MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Where(x=>x.SItemRequestStatus == "Add"))
    .ToList();
```